# How fix hostapd invalid/unknown driver 'nl80211' error?

Tags: wireless, drivers, intel-wireless, hostapd

- I have Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1000
- I installed [hostapd](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/hostapd) from Ubuntu Software Center
- When I run this command `hostapd hostapd-minimal.conf` I get this:

  ```
  root@tarek-PC:~# hostapd hostapd-minimal.conf
  Configuration file: hostapd-minimal.conf
  Line 2: invalid/unknown driver 'nl80211 '
  Line 4: unknown hw_mode 'g '
  2 errors found in configuration file 'hostapd-minimal.conf'
  ```

---

After doing `make` first I had this error:

```
driver_nl80211.c:25:26: warning: netlink/attr.h: No such file or directory
```

I solved it by installing `libnl-1.0pre8`

Now I have this error when doing `make` command:

```
../src/crypto/crypto_openssl.c:10:30: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [../src/crypto/crypto_openssl.o] Error 1
```

Can anyone help me with that error I am running Ubuntu 13.04?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to build, or obtain, a different copy of hostapd.  The one you have has been built with the option `CONFIG_DRIVER_NL80211` set to `N`, rather than `Y`.

There are simple and detailed instructions how to rebuild it here → [Hostapd building instruction](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/hostapd). Rebuild it with the option enabled.   You may have to google for hostapd.2.0.tar.gz, but do exactly as it mentioned in link.

As for the follow-up question/error try to install this library `libssl-dev` using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Comment: thank you for answer when I was following "Hostapd building instruction" I had an error. I edited my question please read my question for the error details if you want to help me

Comment: Ok try this solution above.

Comment: thank you **pourjour** for helping your solutions worked with me :) .I get sick from this now I have got a new error please see this [question] (http://askubuntu.com/questions/298368/how-to-fix-could-not-connect-to-kernel-driver-hostapd-error) if you want to help me

Comment: This worked for me as well.  I was trying to get my ErleRobotics PXFMini + RPiZero drone working with a Ralink RT5370 adapter I already had.  When I pulled down the source for hostapd it already had CONFIG_DRIVER_NL80211 set to Y.  So I just had to pull down the source and build it without making any changes.  I did have to comment out some unsupported settings in the hostapd.conf file that came with the SDcard image from erlerobotics like DEVICENAME and MANUFACTURER.  But now it works great!

Answer (score 5):

You see the spaces after the values? Remove them.

- Line 2: `invalid/unknown driver 'nl80211 '`
- Line 4: `unknown hw_mode 'g '`

Comment: Don't know who have voted down, but it's the correct answer. In the config file there is a trailing space on many lines. This is the reason of the error. After removing them, it works. Thank you.

Comment: I had simular problem when cutting/pasting a hostapd.conf from a website: hostapd is due to a bad implementation very sensitive to whitespaces. Also make sure your interface=<device> in hostapd.conf does not end with a space character, you will get a strange "nl80211: Register Action command failed: ret=-19" error otherwise...

Answer (score 1):

Check for EOL format. It should be in UNIX format as < LF > and not < CR >< LF >.
That fixed mine error.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar Problem, but without the spaces after the values and managed to solve it:

Before I encountered the Problem, I copied the hostapd.conf file from my Windows pc onto my Raspberry Pi. And I believe the problem was, that the text had special characters. Maybe some returns were different (Because **I had a return instead of a space** after the values in the errors)

But enough speculation, let's come to my solution:

1. **I renamed the old hostapd.conf file (to hostapdOld.conf)**
2. **I created a new file with the name hostapd.conf**
3. **And then I copied the whole content of the old file to the new one.** (I just selected the whole text, didn't use Ctrl+A, if this even matters)

Then I ran hostapd as usual, with:

```
sudo hostapd -d /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

And it worked again